# What is Milnor fiber?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a map with $0\in\mathbb{C}$ a critical value. Let $X_0=f^{-1}(0)$ and $x\in X_0$, then the map $F:\frac{f}{|f|}:S_{\varepsilon,x}\setminus(S_{\varepsilon,x}\cap X_0)\to S^1$, where $S_{\varepsilon,x}$ is a sphere, is the Milnor fibration. The Milnor fiber $F_{x}$ at $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is then defined as the fiber of $F$ at $x$.

Here's the question: $x$ isn't even in the domain of the Milnor fibration, how can one find its fiber?

The note I read ([https://people.math.wisc.edu/~maxim/vanishing.pdf](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Emaxim/vanishing.pdf)) has a rather confusing figure:
[image]

Comment: Your definition in your post does not agree with the definition in the note. See page 3.

Comment: If I understand your concern, it is the terminology which is bothering you : the Milnor fiber at $x$ is indeed not a fiber "over $x$", but, on the contrary, lives in a nearby fiber. In the picture, the Milnor fiber $F_x$ is seen as a subspace over $s$ (that is $F_x\subset X_s$). It is called Milnor fiber at $x$ because it gives a lot of information about the singularity at $x$ and depends only of $x$.

Comment: @Roland Oh now I get it! Thank you so much!